# get date with of a day with respect to a given date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the date of a day with respect to a particular date. Suppose i give A=date(22/07/2014) and sunday as input then the output should be date of coming sunday with respect to A date here the output will be 27 july.
Thanks in advance

edit: merge comment

tried with

```
dayto=7; 
var td = new Date(); 
var nextSunday= new Date( td.getFullYear(), 
                          td.getMonth(),
                          td.getDate() + (dayto-td.getDay()) );
```

but it returns in respect to today's date and if i change td variable with any other date then it do not works

Comment: Sounds great, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: tried with dayto=7; var td = new Date(); var nextSunday= new Date(td.getFullYear(),td.getMonth(),td.getDate()+(dayto-td.getDay()));     but it returns in respect to today's date and if i change td variable with any other date then it do not works

Comment: Have a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you're going to be using dates throughout your application. If it's just for 1 thing then it may be unnecessary though.

[This section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) in particular may be of use to you

Comment: In what what does it no work? It seems to work to me...
Maybe you're not parsing the date correctly into td?

Comment: That should be fine. How are you constructing your `Date`? It can be annoying to get right in JS, particularly with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
<script>    
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
function findDayDate(date, dayInput) {

    var d = new Date(Date.parse(date));
    var day = days[ d.getDay() ];

    while(true) {
        if (day.toLowerCase() === dayInput.toLowerCase()) {
            break;
        } else {
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            day = days[ d.getDay() ];
        }
    }
    return d;
}

document.write(findDayDate("2005-07-08", "sunday"));

</script>
```